# T-SQL - How to count the total number of rows containing a substring inside a column for numerous multiple substrings in only one request?

Tags: sql-server, string, count

This web site has been so useful to me for years. There was always the question (and the answer) to my SQL questions. This time, I couldn’t find it. So here is my question:

For a search engine with numerous criteria, I have several columns containing several data / substrings in each.

Say :

```
Ref    |    application         |        type     |             source
_______________________________________________________________________________    
A      |      ak, bct, rg-t     |rega, mann, itr  | abc, ghf, eeerr, lam, rmn    
B      |      ak                |rega, aze        | null        
C      |     rg-t               | null            |         abc, ghf,
D      |     ak                 |rega, mann, itr  | abc, ghf, eeerr, lam, rmn    
E      |    null                |rega             | lam, rmn
```

Each code / substring is supposed to be unique

In only one request, I would like to know how many occurrences there is of `ak`, how many occurrences of `bct`, how many occurrences of `rg-t`…

Is there a way that would correspond to:

```
Select 
   count(application(ak)), 
   count(application(bct)), 
   count(application(rg-t)),
   … 
   count(type(rega)), 
   count(type(aze)), 
   … 
   count(source(abc)),
   count(source(eeerr))
   …
```

And would give one line:

```
3   |1  |2  |…  |4  |1  |…      |3  |2  |…
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Relational databse table column containing comma-separated lists of values - is the first indicator of bad schema design. Consider refactoring your table to one-to many relations instead of these values-lists.

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid to hear that ; ) It would be much cleaner and quicker obviously. But it means a big change to be done on 80 000 lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment made by @AndyKorneyev that it would be BEST if you just had your data normalized. Working with what you have though, you can use `SUM()` function.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90c76/1/0)

```
SELECT
  -- Application counts
   SUM( CASE WHEN application LIKE '%ak%' THEN 1 ELSE 0  END ) AS application_count
  ,SUM( CASE WHEN application LIKE '%bct%' THEN 1 ELSE 0  END ) AS bct_count
  ,SUM( CASE WHEN application LIKE '%rg-t%' THEN 1 ELSE 0  END ) AS rgt_count
  -- Type counts
  ,SUM( CASE WHEN type LIKE '%rega%' THEN 1 ELSE 0  END ) AS rega_count
  ,SUM( CASE WHEN type LIKE '%aze%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS aze_count
  -- Source counts
  ,SUM( CASE WHEN [source] LIKE '%abce%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS abc_count
  ,SUM( CASE WHEN [source] LIKE '%eeerr%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS eeerr_count
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Many thanks Chizzle, that's exactly what I was looking for. That's perfect, even though I agree, the best would be to reorganized the data properly. And many thanks to the other contributors.

Comment: I would like to note that this solution is only safe if the codes do not overlap in there spelling. For example, if one code is ak, and another code is rrrak, the results would be inaccurate. Splitting on the comma is probably the best solution overall

Comment: Yes, obviously. No problem about that. We use to deal with the codes to avoid this kind of problem. Anyway thank you for this warning.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said, you should consider changing your data model...

If you have to deal with it, this query gives you a list of occurences and counts:

```
declare @data table(Ref varchar(10), application varchar(100), type varchar(100), source varchar(100))
insert into @data(Ref, application, type, source) values
('A','ak, bct, rg-t','rega, mann, itr','abc, ghf, eeerr, lam, rmn')  
, ('B','ak','rega, aze',null       )
, ('C','rg-t',null,'abc, ghf, ')
, ('D','ak','rega, mann, itr','abc, ghf, eeerr, lam, rmn    ')
, ('E',null,'rega','lam, rmn')

Select t, v, count = count(*)
From (
    Select Ref, t
        , v = LTRIM(RTRIM(x.d.value('.[1]','varchar(100)')))
    From (
        Select Ref, t = 'application'
            , xml = CAST('<Root><Data>' + REPLACE(application,',','</Data><Data>') + '</Data></Root>' AS XML)
        From @data
        Union All
        Select Ref, t = 'type'
            , xml = CAST('<Root><Data>' + REPLACE(type,',','</Data><Data>') + '</Data></Root>' AS XML)
        From @data
        Union All
        Select Ref, t = 'source'
            , xml = CAST('<Root><Data>' + REPLACE(source,',','</Data><Data>') + '</Data></Root>' AS XML)
        From @data
    ) t
    Cross Apply xml.nodes('/Root/Data')x(d)
) as list
Where v <> ''
Group By t, v
Order By t, v
```

Output:

```
t           | v     | count
application | ak    | 3
application | bct   | 1
application | rg-t  | 2
source      | abc   | 3
source      | eeerr | 2
source      | ghf   | 3
source      | lam   | 3
source      | rmn   | 3
type        | aze   | 1
type        | itr   | 2
type        | mann  | 2
type        | rega  | 4
```

The subquery split your comma separated values by converting each value to xml. It does it 3 times (UNION ALL), once for each column: application, source, type.

It then only have to count them all.

Answer (score 0):

I had to "normalise" your data before we could do the aggregation:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Ref] varchar(1), [application] varchar(13), [type] varchar(15), [source] varchar(25))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Ref], [application], [type], [source])
VALUES
    ('A', 'ak, bct, rg-t', 'rega, mann, itr', 'abc, ghf, eeerr, lam, rmn'),
    ('B', 'ak', 'rega, aze', NULL),
    ('C', 'rg-t', NULL, 'abc, ghf'),
    ('D', 'ak', 'rega, mann, itr', 'abc, ghf, eeerr, lam, rmn'),
    ('E', NULL, 'rega', 'lam, rmn')
;

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 'Application' AS [Type]
, CAST('<r>' + REPLACE([Application], ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS [Value]
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Type' AS [Type]
, CAST('<r>' + REPLACE([Type], ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS [Value]
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Source' AS [Type]
, CAST('<r>' + REPLACE([Source], ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS [Value]
FROM Table1)
, CTE2 AS (
SELECT [Type], LTRIM(RTRIM(xTable.xColumn.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))) AS [Value]
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY [Value].nodes('//r') AS xTable(xColumn))
SELECT [Type], [Value], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM CTE2
GROUP BY [Type], [Value]
ORDER BY [Type], [Value]
```